# How to check if inner <div> has text

Tags: javascript, jquery

what I'm trying to do is to check if my inner `<div>` has a text for example Ended and then remove if it has a text. I have multiple `<div>` with the same `class` name. I tried using `.filter()`. I would like to remove the div `container_one` that contains the found element.

Here is my HTML:

```js
var $filstatus = $('.status').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == 'Ended';
});

$filstatus.remove();
```

```html
<div class="main_container">

  <div class="container_one">
    <div class="inner_container">
      <div class="status">Ended</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container_one">
    <div class="inner_container">
      <div class="status">On going</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container_one">
    <div class="inner_container">
      <div class="status">Ended</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You want to remove the div or the text ?

Comment: Did you try `return $(this).html()` unstead of `return $(this).text()`?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui the whole div of `container_one`

Comment: so you are trying to remove div with `Ended` text?

Comment: your code works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/n3d5fwqj/    where are you using your jquery?

Comment: Please define "_it doesn't work_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the jQuery's [selector by content](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)
combined with [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/). This might be the shortest way:

```js
$('.status:contains("Ended")', $('.main_container')).closest('.container_one').remove();
```

First `('.status:contains("Ended")')` will select all elements that have a class `status`, contain the text "Ended" and are children of `main_container` (not needed but is recommended to speed up selection of elements on complex pages).

Then the method `.closest('container_one')` will climb up the parents tree for each of the elements from the previous step and select the first parent element with class 'container_one'.

At last it will remove all elements found.

**Note:** all those methods work both with single element and collections of elements, so no need of any `for/foreach`.

[Working JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/21681/)

Answer (score 1):

Pure JavaScript solution with `forEach`:

```js
var div = document.querySelectorAll('.container_one');
div.forEach(function(el){
  var target = el.querySelector('.status');
  if(target.textContent == 'Ended'){
    el.remove();
  };
})
```

```html
<div class="main_container">

  <div class="container_one">
    <div class="inner_container">
      <div class="status">Ended</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container_one">
    <div class="inner_container">
      <div class="status">On going</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container_one">
    <div class="inner_container">
      <div class="status">Ended</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$filstatus.parent().parent().remove();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18735655)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MU  what's wrong with answering the question? this does what the OP requested https://jsfiddle.net/n3d5fwqj/2/

Comment: You should provide some explanation etc. At SO the quality of answers is important.

Answer (score 0):

`filter` will return an array , then use `each` to loop over that and delete the element. In this case it will remove that specific div but the parent div will still be in dom

```js
var $filstatus = $('.status').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() === 'Ended';
});
$filstatus.each(function(index, elem) {
  $(elem).remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_container">

  <div class="container_one">
    <div class="inner_container">
      <div class="status">Ended</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container_one">
    <div class="inner_container">
      <div class="status">On going</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container_one">
    <div class="inner_container">
      <div class="status">Ended</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: jQuery `filter` method returns a jQuery object, which "loops itself" when needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `.container_one` whose inner child has the text `Ended`, try

```
const ended = $('.status').filter((index, element) => $(element).text() === 'Ended')

ended.parents('.container_one').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to remove the closest ansistor with class `.container_one`, you will need to use `closest`

```
$filstatus.closest(".container_one").remove();
```

Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/n3d5fwqj/1/

https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem is you are able to remove the child div `status` but what you want is to remove the entire parent div with class `container_one`

you can use `$.each` for that and use `closest(class_name)` to remove the parent including its child

```
  $.each($('.status'), function(idx, div) {
      if ($(this).text() == 'Ended') {
        $(this).closest('.container_one').remove();
      }
  });
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/21673/)

or you can continue your filter and just add `.closest('.container_one')` to your jquery selector

```
  var $filstatus = $('.status').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Ended';
  });

  $filstatus.closest('.container_one').remove();
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/21674/)

Comment: I will try it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using this if you don't need $filstatus in other places

```
$('.status').each(function(){
  if ($(this).text() == "Ended"){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  }
})
```

Comment: for example I have 5 parent then I should put 5 `.parent()` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid you have to. (Just realized you can try .closet() too)